# Why are values from appsettings.Development.json appearing in production?

Tags: asp.net, azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service

According to [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#azure-app-service), "Production is the default value if DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT have not been set. Apps deployed to Azure are Production by default." I did not have those values set in the configuration of my Azure App Service, yet in my injected IConfiguration in code I am seeing a value from `appsettings.Development.json` instead of `appsettings.json`. I also tried explicitly setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT equal to "Production", but the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm if either ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT nor DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT is set in the Azure App Service configuration?

Comment: When you publish your code to Azure what is the mode you choose? Debug mode or Release Mode?

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs` and `.csproj` file

Comment: It will be easy for me to repro from my end if you provide `appsettings.Development.json` and  `appsettings.json`.

Comment: I have checked from my end,Iam able to see only the values from `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: [LocalApp](https://i.imgur.com/oFvghqO.png) [DeployedApp](https://i.imgur.com/4nON0Q9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue. I also had the environment variables set in the `web.config` from a long time ago (pre-Azure). Removing these old values fixed the problem.

[image: web.config values]

Answer (score 1):

> "Production is the default value if DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT have not been set.

Yes, the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` after deploying the Web App to Azure App Service will be Production.

- You can check that by retrieving the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value in `.cshtml` page.

```cs
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment Environment
<h3>ASPNETCORE ENVIRONMENT: @Environment.EnvironmentName</h3>
```

***Environment Output:***

[image]

- I have set sample App Settings value in `appsettings.Development.json` file.

```cs
  "TestVal": "Value from appsettings.Development.json"
```

- And Iam retrieving the value in `.cshtml` page using the below code.

```cs
@inject IConfiguration myconfig;
<h3>TestVal:  @myconfig["TestVal"]</h3>
```

***Local Output:***

[image]

***Deployed App Output:***

As I have set the same in `appsettings.json` , the value from `appsettings.json` file is loaded.

[image]

- If the `appsettings.json` file does not have the above setting, then the value will be null.

[image]

- If you set the `json` file in `Program.cs` as below, only that file values will be loaded.

```cs
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", true, true);
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Make sure you have not set the `json` file as mentioned above.